# ZipArchieves downloaded is unreadable

Tags: php, download, php-ziparchive

I am trying to download files within folder `my_folder`. Making zip files on the file and downlod it using php. Here is what I tried.

```
<?php

$path = '/my_folder/path/';
$handle=opendir($path); 
$files = array();
while(false!==($file = readdir($handle)))
 {
    $files[] = $path . $file;
 }
$zipname = 'file.zip';
$zip = new ZipArchive;
if($zip->open($zipname, ZipArchive::CREATE) == TRUE){
    foreach ($files as $file) {
      $zip->addFile($file);
    }
    $zip->close();
}

header('Content-Type: application/zip');
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=filename.zip');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($zipname));
header("Pragma: no-cache"); 
header("Expires: 0");
readfile($zipname);
unlink($zipname);
?>
```

It works perfectly fine it seems. It downloads zip file but when I tried to extract zip, it gives password dialogue box with error message `Archieve non readable; Would you like to try a password`
Can any one tell me whats wrong in code or how to avoid this dialogue and extract files ?